# Пишу код на Python. И выдает ошибку про не поддержку кодировки UTF-8. (кодовый редактор Visual Studio Code в стандартном редакторе python такого нету)

Tags: python

Пишу код на говорящего робота в python. В кодовом редакторе Visual Studio Code. Выдает ошибку:

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xd1' in file C:\Users\Аркадий\Desktop\Bob\bobo.py on line 32, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

В стандартном редакторе IDLE такого нету.

Comment: И в чем вопрос-то? В самой ошибке написано, что нужно сделать и где об этом написано.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте написать в первой строке вот это:

```
# coding: utf8
```

именно комментарием